# Is cache.xml mandatory to have in ehcache?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ehcache

I want to start using ehcache-1.2.3.jar in my project.   But I want to know if it is mandatory to build cache.xml?

If yes then why and If no then what situations it might be useful to build cache.xml.
Following is sample code.

```
 CacheManager.getInstance().addCache("MyCache");
 Cache c= CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("MyCache");
 Employee emp=new Employee();
 emp.setEmpName("Ramji");
 Element e=new Element("emp", emp);
 c.put(e );
```

Comment: Why would you want to use ehcache-1.2.3 which was released in 2006? You would be much better looking at the latest version, 2.9.0 at this time.

Answer (score 0):

When you meant cache.xml, do you mean ehcache.xml? If yes, configuration in an XML file is not mandatory but it is recommended.  If you think XML-based configuration doesn't work for you, you can do it through JAVA as well (refer to the URL below).
It is recommended to have the configuration in an XML because you would want to change it during deployment for example.

Source: http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration